# Undefined simbol in shared library

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, bjam

I have a shared library `shared_lib.so`. I have a python wrapper using `CFFI` that calls this shared library using some arguments.
`shared_lib.so` was created using `Jamfile` as:

```
lib shared_lib :
    [ glob config/calculate_param.cpp ]
    ds-testing-deps
    ../raster_inserter
    ../ri_coresynth//ri_coresynth
    ../metsynth//synth_generic
;
```

To interact with the dynammic library from Python I do:

```
ffi = FFI()

ffi.cdef("""
    typedef struct {
        char strs[30];
        double value;
    } par_t;

   double calculate(...);
""")

lib = ffi.dlopen('./libshared_lib.so')

dout = lib.calculate(...)
```

`calculate_param.cpp` imports and executes some parts of a `utils.h` file (called from the function `calculate`), and while executing this `utils.h` I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  error looking up symbol 'load_functions' in '/home/hesteban/Documents/Dataserver/dataserver/test/config/./libshared_lib.so': ./libshared_lib.so: undefined symbol: load_functions
[1]    24107 abort (core dumped)  python3 ./wrapper_model_dev.py
```

The basic structure of `utils.h` is:

```
class Bootstrap {
public:
    void init(const std::string& prefix, int argc, char* argv[]) {
        Synth_builder sb;
        sb.load_functions(...);
    }
}
```

To check whether `load_function` is a simbol or not I do:

```
$nm libshared_lib.so | grep load_functions
0000000000a05cfc W _ZN10dataserver4test9Bootstrap14load_functionsERN5synth7BuilderINS2_8StrategyINS0_14Test_parameterEdiEEEE
0000000000ce8c2e W _ZN5synth7BuilderINS_8StrategyIN10dataserver16Cache_synth_nodeEdiEEE14load_functionsEN5boost10filesystem4pathEbNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
0000000000ce8dc6 W _ZN5synth7BuilderINS_8StrategyIN10dataserver17Source_synth_nodeEdiEEE14load_functionsEN5boost10filesystem4pathEbNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
0000000000a0a75c W _ZN5synth7BuilderINS_8StrategyIN10dataserver4test14Test_parameterEdiEEE14load_functionsEN5boost10filesystem4pathEbNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Comment: So you have c++ code in which you call `load_functions` that is in `shared_lib.so`?  How do you link against that shared library? You only show how you create `shared_lib` but you don't show how you link your program against it.

Comment: I have edit a little bit but it is hard to summarize everything in a small example. `shard_lib.so` is a shared library that has a function called `calculate` thatcalls the `utils.h` file, which is where I have the problem